# Ни могу записать Z буфер в текстуру

Tags: java, android, opengl

Пытаюсь записать Z буфер в текстуру.
Создаю текстуру.

```
// Создаем новую текстуру
int i[] = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, i,0);
m_shadowMap = i[0];
if (m_shadowMap == 0) Log.e("genTexture","m_shadowMap = "+m_shadowMap);
// Связываю текстуру  с 2D текстурой
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowMap);
// заполняю текстуру в формате буфера глубены
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, null);
// Фильтры
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
// Cоздаем буффер кадра
GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, i, 0);
m_fbo = i[0];
if (m_fbo == 0) Log.e("genTexture","m_fbo = "+m_fbo);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);

//GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
// Указываю буфферу кадра что бы рисовал в текстуру только буффер глубены
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowMap, 0);


int Status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

if (Status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ) {
    Log.e("genTexture","GL_FRAMEBUFFER error: "+Status);
    Log.e("genTexture","width: "+width+"  height: "+height);
}
```

Заполняю текстуру так:

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_ALWAYS);
GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
GLES20.glPolygonOffset(2.0f,500.0f);
float matrixViewShadow[] = new float[16];
float matrixViewProgectShadow[] = new float[16];
float matrixProgectShadow[] = new float[16];
Matrix.setLookAtM(matrixViewShadow,0, 1,3,5, 0,0,0,   0, 1, 0);
Matrix.orthoM(matrixProgectShadow, 0, 0, width, 0,height, -1, 50); 
Matrix.multiplyMM(matrixViewProgectShadow, 0, projectionMatrix , 0,matrixViewShadow, 0);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
surfaceShadow.Draw(matrixViewProgectShadow,0);
cube.setPos(0, 0.5f, 0);
cube.Draw(projectionMatrix, matrixViewShadow);

GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Далее вывожу с помощью фрагментного шейдера:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform float uTemp;
varying vec2 vTexcoord;
void main() {
  if (uTemp == 1.0)
  {
        float Depth = texture2D(uTexture, vTexcoord).z;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(Depth), 1.0);
  } else
  {

  }
}
```

В результате выводится пустая текстура!

Я вот еще что не понимаю, в памяти во float хранят данные, так с каким параметром их выводить и почему? x y z w?

Comment: При любом раскладе, наверно вы захотите проверять все каналы текстуры, а не только `b` (алиас `z`) - `vec4 Depth = texture2D(uTexture, vTexcoord);`

Comment: Учтите, что результат в текстуре глубины может быть очень приближен к 0 или к 1. Так что попробуйте сделать вывод в виде `pow(Depth, 128.0)` или `pow(1.0 - Depth, 128.0)`

Comment: Спасибо получилось ошибка на самом деле была что при создании текстуры я выбирал формат хранения GL_FLOAT а нужно было integer

Comment: Если решило - запостите это более подробным ответом и примите )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было использовать GL_UNSIGNED_INT

```
    // Создаем новую текстуру
    int i[] = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, i,0);
    m_shadowMap = i[0];
    if (m_shadowMap == 0) Log.e("genTexture","m_shadowMap = "+m_shadowMap);
    // Связываю текстуру  с 2D текстурой
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowMap);
    // заполняю текстуру в формате буфера глубены
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, null);
    // Фильтры
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    // Cоздаем буффер кадра
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, i, 0);
    m_fbo = i[0];
    if (m_fbo == 0) Log.e("genTexture","m_fbo = "+m_fbo);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);

    //GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    // Указываю буфферу кадра что бы рисовал в текстуру только буффер глубены
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowMap, 0);


    int Status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    if (Status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ) {
        Log.e("genTexture","GL_FRAMEBUFFER error: "+Status);
        Log.e("genTexture","width: "+width+"  height: "+height);
    }
```